# Using sensor in android to detect a jump

Tags: java, android, sensors

First of all I am only getting started with android and java so please be indulgent.

So, i want to make a "jump" detector using the sensor in Android devices.
Basically i want to use the information returned by my sensor and compare it to detect if the user jumped or not.
Physics is pretty simple, I only need two very close value (a jump last for about a second) of the Y-axis and compare the average of these two values to a "limit value".

My main problem is I don't know how to get two differents values from my sensor.
I tried to use the System.currentTimeMillis() to catch a value at a very specific moment and compare it with a older or newer value, but it doesn't seem to work very well.

Here is my code.

```
public  void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    acceleration.setText("X: " +event.values[0]+ " Y:" +event.values[1] + "Z: " +event.values[2] +"Nombre de sauts" +saut);
    Yacc = event.values[1];

    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lastUpdate = curTime - 400;
    if((curTime - lastUpdate)>390){
        lastUpdate = curTime;
        float moyY = (Yacc - last_Yacc)/2;


        if(moyY > 5){
            saut = saut +1;
        }

    compteur.setText("currenttime " +curTime + "  lastUpdate "+ lastUpdate +"  saut=" +saut + "  Valeur moyenne" +moyY + "  saut=" +saut);





    }

    last_Yacc = Yacc;

}
```

I thank you all in advance for you consideration.